# Equivalence of Predicate with quantifiers

Tags: logic

I'm to disprove the following equivalence in a general manner outside of examples where we can set p(x,y) equal to a scenario that makes it obvious. In part 1, we used definitions of quantifiers to obtain the answer. In part im looking for something similar that shows regardless of scenario it will always be false.

[image]

Comment: Consider $P(x, y) = x < y$.

Comment: @ureui I understand why in such scenario it would be true, however, I'm looking for a more general answer which disproves it for all cases similar to above. If you could have any hints please share.

Comment: @Josue you do not need to disprove a statement for all interpretaions to show that it is not a tautology; you only need to disprove it in *some* interpretation.  Just one will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this equivalence is false because the reverse implication(Part 2) is false.

The basic idea is this:

$(\forall x)(\exists y)(P(x,y))$ basically means, that given any $x$ you can find a $y$ such that $P(x,y)$. However, this statement doesn't, in any way, indicate that these $y$ s are the same for any $x$. So, there may be 2 $x$ s which require different $y$ s. Hence the reverse implication is false.

You don't even need to use a proof with quantifiers for this. Here's how you can prove it with a non-example.

Suppose $P(x,y)$ means that $y = x$.
Now, for all $x$ you can find a $y$ such that $P(x,y)$. And that's obvious, because you could just take $y=x$ and you'd be done.

However, this doesn't mean that there's one $y$, such that for all $x$ it's equal to $x$, which is also pretty obvious becuase if there *was* a $y$ like this, then any $x$ that you take, *any* $x$, would have to be the same, which is obviously not the case. For example, if the variables here denote real numbers, $x\ne(x+1)$.

So, with this example, we have
$(\forall x)(\exists y)(P(x,y))$ as true, and
$(\exists y)(\forall x)(P(x,y))$ as false
which is practically the definition for $(\forall x)(\exists y)(P(x,y))\;\not\!\!\!\implies(\exists y)(\forall x)(P(x,y))$

Thus, the reverse implication is proven false by non-example. And since the implication is true only in one direction, the equivalence is false.

When you ask for a general answer, I assume you mean that you want an answer $\forall P(x,y)$.

So part 2 would have to prove/disprove that
$\forall P(x,y)[(\forall x)(\exists y)(P(x,y))\implies(\exists y)(\forall x)(P(x,y))]$

The negation of this would be
$\exists P(x,y)[(\forall x)(\exists y)(P(x,y))\;\not\!\!\!\implies(\exists y)(\forall x)(P(x,y))]$.

And this has been proven above. So, the reverse implication is false in general also.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set of the real numbers, and $P(x, y) : x+y=0$. Note that for all $x\in\mathbb{R} $ you can consider $y = - x$ and then $x+y=x-x=0$. However, for all $y\in \mathbb{R} $ there exists $x\in\mathbb{R} $ such that $x+y\neq 0$. Hence, the converse statement is false.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I can see why the converse if false with an example but, I am trying to solve it generally and disprove it for all cases. If there any hints you could give me similar to how part 1 is solved